# Possible explanation for faster execution of two programs in C++ (with Python comparison)?

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, performance, execution-time

Update: The C++ programs (as shown below) were compiled with no additional flags, i.e. `g++ program.cpp`. However raising the optimisation level does not change the fact that brute force runs faster than memoization technique (0.1 second VS 1 second on my machine).

### Context

I try to calculate the  number (< 1 million) with the longest [Collatz sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture). I wrote a brute force algorithm and compared it with the suggested optimised program (which basically uses memoization).

**My question is: What could possibly be the reason that the brute force executes faster than the supposedly optimised (memoization) version in C++ ?**

Below the comparisons I have on my machine (a Macbook Air); the times are in the beginning of the program code in comments.

### C++ (brute force)

```
/**
 * runs in 1 second
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

unsigned long long nextSequence(unsigned long long n)
{
  if (n % 2 == 0)
    return n / 2;
  else
  {
    return 3 * n + 1;
  }
}

int main()
{
  int max_counter = 0;
  unsigned long long result;
  for (size_t i = 1; i < 1000000; i++)
  {
    int counter = 1;
    unsigned long long n = i;
    while (n != 1)
    {
      n = nextSequence(n);
      counter++;
    }
    if (counter > max_counter)
    {
      max_counter = counter;
      result = i;
    }
  }

  std::cout << result << " has " << max_counter << " sequences." << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

### C++ (memoization)

```
/**
 * runs in 2-3 seconds 
 */

#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

int countSequence(uint64_t n, std::unordered_map<uint64_t, uint64_t> &cache)
{
  if (cache.count(n) == 1)
    return cache[n];

  if (n % 2 == 0)
    cache[n] = 1 + countSequence(n / 2, cache);
  else
    cache[n] = 2 + countSequence((3 * n + 1) / 2, cache);

  return cache[n];
}

int main()
{
  uint64_t max_counter = 0;
  uint64_t result;
  std::unordered_map<uint64_t, uint64_t> cache;
  cache[1] = 1;
  for (uint64_t i = 500000; i < 1000000; i++)
  {
    if (countSequence(i, cache) > max_counter)
    {
      max_counter = countSequence(i, cache);
      result = i;
    }
  }

  std::cout << result << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

In Python the memoization technique really runs faster.

### Python (memoization)

```
# runs in 1.5 seconds

def countChain(n):
    if n in values:
        return values[n]
    if n % 2 == 0:
        values[n] = 1 + countChain(n / 2)
    else:
        values[n] = 2 + countChain((3 * n + 1) / 2)
    return values[n]


values = {1: 1}
longest_chain = 0
answer = -1

for number in range(500000, 1000000):
    if countChain(number) > longest_chain:
        longest_chain = countChain(number)
        answer = number

print(answer)
```

### Python (brute force)

```
# runs in 30 seconds


def countChain(n):
    if n == 1:
        return 1
    if n % 2 == 0:
        return 1 + countChain(n / 2)
    return 2 + countChain((3 * n + 1) / 2)


longest_chain = 0
answer = -1

for number in range(1, 1000000):
    temp = countChain(number)
    if temp > longest_chain:
        longest_chain = temp
        answer = number

print(answer)
```

Comment: All optimizer settings on for the c++ versions?

Comment: No, I don't think so. Just compiled with `g++ program.cpp` - I will try to set highest optimisation level in the meantime.

Comment: @Ely -- All questions concerning the speed of a C++ program compared to language X or why one version of the program runs faster than another versoni should be accompanied by the optimization settings used to compile the C++ application.  Otherwise all the timing information being shown becomes meaningless.

Comment: An unordered_map does a lot of dynamic memory allocation, which carries significant penalty as compared to raw CPU-based crunching.

Comment: @Ely Also note that you could use `gprof` to profile your code and detect the actual bottlenecks.

Comment: You do 3 looks-up in C++ version whereas one is enough...

Comment: @Jarod42 You are right. I just corrected the copy & paste mistake for the Python memoization program code. Thanx

Comment: Note that you could speed up almost 2x all your versions by using `(3 * n + 1)/2`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand that your question is about the difference between the two C++ variants and not between the copiled C++ and the interpreted python.  Answering it decisively would require to compile the code with optimizations turned on and profiling its execution. And clarity about whether the compiler target is 64 or 32 bits.

But given the order of magnitude between both versions of the C++ code, a quick inspection already shows that your memoization consumes more resources than it makes you gain.

One important performance bottleneck here is the memory management of the unordered map.  An [`unordered_map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) works with [buckets of items](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table). The map adjust the number of buckets when necessary, but this requires memory allocation (and potentially moving chunks of memory, depending how the buckets are implemented).

Now, if you add the following statement just after the initialisation of the cache, and just before displaying the result, you'll see that there is a huge change in the [number of buckets allocated](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/bucket_count):

```
std::cout << "Bucket count: "<<cache.bucket_count()<<"/"<<cache.max_bucket_count()<<std::endl;
```

To avoid the overhead associated to this, you could preallocate the number of buckets at construction:

```
std::unordered_map<uint64_t, uint64_t> cache(3000000);
```

Doing this in on ideone for a small and informal test saved almost 50% of the performance.

But notheless...  Storing and finding objects in an `unordered_map` requires to calculate hash codes made of a lot of arithmetic operations.  So I guess that these operations are simply heavier than doing the brute force calculations.

Comment: Thank you. I think you answer is very good. I followed your advise to construct the unordered map with the bucket count as per your suggestion. I compiled both versions with `g++ -O3 program.cpp` (suggested in a comment) and both run in the same order of 0.5 seconds on my machine. I also believe that the hash code arithmetic is simply heavier than doing brute force as you said.

Comment: @Ely Thank you for this very interesting confirmation with experimental evidence !

Answer (score 2):

Main memory access is *vastly* slower than computation, so much so that when it's time to care, you should treat anything over a very few (cpu-model-dependent) meg as retrieved from an I/O or network device.

Even fetching from L1 is expensive compared to integer ops.

Long, long ago, this wasn't true.  Computation and memory access were at least in the same ballpark for many decades, because there simply wasn't enough room in the transistor budget to make fast caches large enough to pay.

So people counted CPU operations and just assumed memory could more or less keep up.

Nowadays, it just … can't.  The penalty for a CPU cache miss is *hundreds* of integer ops, and your million-16-byte-entry hash map is pretty much guaranteed to blow not just the cpu's memory caches but also the TLB, which takes the delay penalty  from painful to devastating.